# Locking to prevent concurrent DELETE all + bulk INSERT on same table without blocking SELECTs

Tags: postgresql

In postgres, I have a function like below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_foo(fooelems VARCHAR(20)[]) RETURNS VOID AS $$
    DELETE FROM foo;
    INSERT INTO foo(fooelem, flag) SELECT unnest(fooelems), true;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

It's supposed to delete everything from the table foo, and insert 1 record for each entry in the passed array, with flag as true.

If I run 2 instances of these concurrently with different data from different sessions, I sometimes get the end result which has data of both. How to make it such that the end state only contains one of the inputs (i.e. the 2 invocations are done serially). SELECTs on the table should not be blocked.

What I mean is if I run these 2 statements from different sessions (I'm adding a random duration sleep in between delete & insert):

`select update_foo(['a', 'b', 'c']);`
`select update_foo(['d', 'e', 'f']);`

I sometimes get the foo table to contain all 6, whereas I only want it to be either have (a, b, c) or (d, e, f).

Answer (score 1):

Make the first statement in the function be a LOCK TABLE.  You have to lock in a mode which is self-exclusive, but doesn't block SELECT.  Looking [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html), there seem to be three choices which do that (Exclusive, Share Row Exclusive, and Share Update Exclusive), so look at what the other effects each of them has to see which would be best for you.

Share Update Exclusive would act as a signal here.  It will block DELETEs and INSERTs emanating from the same function only because the other invocation of the same function will also try to acquire Share Update Exclusive and block.  The other two choices will directly block DELETEs and INSERTs, regardless of what source they come from.